# Why does a remote EJB Call throw a org.jboss.remoting.serialization.ClassLoaderUtility Exception?

Tags: java, security, jboss, ejb

I have a login module which calls a remote EJB (JBOSS 5.1) to get a javax.security.auth.Subject:

```
public Subject getSubject (String a, String b) throws FailedLoginException
```

On the remote side the subject is filled as follows:

```
MyOwnPrincipalInterface principal = (MyOwnPrincipalInterface)new MyOwnPrincipalImpl("name");
subject.getPrincipals().add(principal);
```

The client always throws a Exception:

```
        ...
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.packages.MyOwnPrincipalImpl
org.jboss.remoting.serialization.ClassLoaderUtility.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtility.java:103)
        ...
```

The client has access to the Interfaces, but not the implementations. It seems that the client needs the implementations to unmarshall the objects. Why is this so? Can it been turned off? I would rather not have the implementations in the client, because it makes changes so much harder.

In http://docs.jboss.org/jbossremoting/docs/guide/2.2/html/ch07.html it only says, that classes are needed for unmashalling. I see no reason, why the Interfaces are not sufficent for this.

Comment: Do see anything suspicious in server side logs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems some issue with classloading. I found [this](http://community.jboss.org/message/563767) post of the forum. The issue being faced is similar. See if this helps you.