# Remote EJB Call throws a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.0

I am getting a following exception in the client, this exception comes very rarely though.
If the class is not found, then this error should come every time, but this error comes very rarely.

We have our swing application deployed on jboss 5.1 server.

We have two main components :

Client- The client code that communicates with the server and renders the Java Swing components.

Server- The server code responsible for sending the screen and event data to the client.

Client communicates with the server using a EJB Container.

**Stacktrace :**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tools.project.server.CustomUtil
    at org.jboss.remoting.serialization.ClassLoaderUtility.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtility.java:103)
    at org.jboss.remoting.loading.RemotingClassLoader.loadClass(RemotingClassLoader.java:86)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.remoting.loading.ObjectInputStreamWithClassLoader.resolveClass(ObjectInputStreamWithClassLoader.java:179)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.remoting.serialization.impl.java.JavaSerializationManager.receiveObjectVersion2_2(JavaSerializationManager.java:238)
    at org.jboss.remoting.serialization.impl.java.JavaSerializationManager.receiveObject(JavaSerializationManager.java:138)
    at org.jboss.remoting.marshal.serializable.SerializableUnMarshaller.read(SerializableUnMarshaller.java:123)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.versionedRead(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:1220)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.transport(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:850)
    at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:165)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:1724)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:629)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.ClusterChooserInterceptor.invoke(ClusterChooserInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.security.client.SecurityClientInterceptor.invoke(SecurityClientInterceptor.java:65)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.ClusteredIsLocalInterceptor.invoke(ClusteredIsLocalInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.PojiProxy.invoke(PojiProxy.java:62)
    at $Proxy3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:207)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:164)
    at $Proxy2.getMessagingBuffer(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error will only occur when the server sends an object to the client that references a `com.tools.project.server.CustomUtil`. Either add `com.tools.project.server.CustomUtil` to the client class loader or remove the reference from the server response.

Comment: It is not the case, since it is not occuring everytime.   I have found following link related to this issue but there is no resolution.           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035574/why-does-a-remote-ejb-call-throw-a-org-jboss-remoting-serialization-classloaderu

Comment: And this issue occurs only when we throw exception. I am suspecting that when exception error stacktrace length exceeds some limit, class not found issue occurs in remote classloading.

Comment: Do your exceptions reference `com.tools.project.server.CustomUtil`?

Comment: Yes, my exception reference CustomUtil class.

Comment: As I said earlier, from a remote client we are doing EJB invocations using JNDI..

Comment: There's your problem, your exceptions are serialized just like normal exceptions. They reference `com.tools.project.server.CustomUtil` which is not available on the client.

Comment: But why it is not happening every time I throw an exception ?

Comment: It should happen for every of your exception that reference `com.tools.project.server.CustomUtil` **and** get sent to the client.

Comment: If the reference to CustomUtil is initialized in some method (e.g. by creating an instance or accessing a static member), this would happen only when accessing the reference is actually attempted.